# Ask CSS for Website

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to ask some question about css. I want to make a website that use css to design it.. But I'm stuck with the css code that make me confused..

Here the web I want to be :
[image]

The content of the web only 1000px in the middle, and the one that I made is like this :

[image]

I don't know how to make the corner to be like that, like ribbon corner. And I want to make the rest of ribbon that longer into the end of website (it's still proportional if you zoom in or zoom out)

The second question is when I try to open it at mozilla, it's will be a mess at the login box like this :
[image]

Here's the code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            a{
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            html{
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }

            body {
                margin:0px;
                font-size:8pt;
                font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
                background-color:#ffbeec;
            }

            .clearBoth{
                clear:both;
            }

            #divHeader{
                height:321px;
            }

            #menuHeader{
                height:50px;
                background-color:#93113d;
            }

            #isiMenuHeader {
                margin:0px auto;
                width:1000px;
                height:100%;

                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#93113d, endColorstr=#d41a59);
                background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#93113d), color-stop(50%,#d41a59),color-stop(100%,#93113d));
            }

            #logoHeader{
                height:221px;
                background-color:#000000;
            }

            #isiLogoHeader{
                margin:0px auto;
                width:1000px;
                height:100%;
                background-color:#000;
            }

            #lineHeader{
                height:13px;
                background-color:#986f39;
            }

            #isiLineHeader{
                margin:0px auto;
                width:1000px;
                height:100%;

                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#986f39, endColorstr=#d3944d);
                background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #986f39 0%, #d3944d 50%,#986f39 100%);
                background-image:linear-gradient(left, #986f39 0%, #d3944d 50%,#986f39 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #986f39 0%, #d3944d 50%,#986f39 100%);
                background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #986f39 0%, #d3944d 50%,#986f39 100%);
                background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #986f39 0%, #d3944d 50%,#986f39 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#986f39), color-stop(50%,#d3944d),color-stop(100%,#986f39));
            }

            #menu2Header{
                height:37px;
                background-color:#93113d;
            }

            #isiMenu2Header{
                margin:0px auto;
                width:1000px;
                height:100%;

                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#93113d, endColorstr=#d41a59);
                background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #93113d 0%, #d41a59 50%,#93113d 100%);
                background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#93113d), color-stop(50%,#d41a59),color-stop(100%,#93113d));
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divHeader">
            <div id="menuHeader">
                <div id="isiMenuHeader">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        dsfasfas
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;background-color:#f782af;height:52px;width:241px;margin-top:24px;">
                        dsfdsfds
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearBoth"></div>

            <div id="logoHeader" style="margin-top:-26px">
                <div id="isiLogoHeader">
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:24px;position:absolute;">
                        <img src="images/logo.png">
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;color:#fff;margin-right:34px;margin-top:50px;">
                        <div>
                            Member Login<br>
                            <input type="text" style="width:204px"><br>
                            <input type="text" style="width:156px">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            What are you looking for?<br>
                            <input type="text" style="width:156px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearBoth"></div>

            <div id="lineHeader"><div id="isiLineHeader"></div></div> <!--136-->

            <div id="menu2Header">
                <div id="isiMenu2Header">
                    sdasdsas
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>

        <div class="clearBoth"></div>

        <div id="divBody"> <!--86-->
            <div style="margin:0px auto;width:1000px;height:100%;">
                sfasfasdfas
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.. Hope someone can help me.. Thank you... :)

Comment: nd_macias' answer is good. you can see more shapes here http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: thank you.. I use nd_macias's answer.. hehe.. and maybe I can use the other shape someday.. thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for ribbon corner you could use this piece of code:

**HTML**

```
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid pink;
  border-bottom: 50px solid pink;
}
```

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEspu)

It should work in all major browsers, includes IE8 (not IE7).

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about a css ribbon but you can position the ribbon absolute and set right 0

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of nd_macias' solution, try adding these also:

```
div:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 2500px;
height: 100px;
background: pink;
}
```

That will extend the pink to the right of your ribbon. Then, since the width of your container div is set to 1000px, and I'm assuming you won't be using the spaces to the left and right of it for anything important, set overflow-x: hidden on your body tag. Adding onto your current CSS, you get:

```
body {
margin:0px;
font-size:8pt;
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
background-color:#ffbeec;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[see here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tdquF)

Comment: thank you for give the way how to make the ribbon longer.. it's work! thank you very much